# Object too fast for Collision in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, simulation, game-engine, collision

I'm currently making a simulation where disks are placed in a conveyor belt and sorted by color. When the sensor detects a white disk, a rectangular object 'pushes' out of the conveyor belt into a box, and it needs to move quickly. However, whenever we set the speed to a high number it just goes through the disks, without pushing them. I have already tried making the pushing object's collision detection 'Continuous dynamic' (RigidBody) and the disks' collision detection 'Continuous' (like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XvrFQJ3n8Mo). I have attached an image of how the mentioned part of the robot looks and the settings for both the disk and pusher object.

disk and pusher object settings
[image: disk and pusher object settings]

visualisation of robot simulation
[image: visualisation of robot simulation]

Comment: what if you tick "Interpolate" (that may, IMO, compute positions in between to check for collisions)?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately ticking interpolate for just the pusher, just the disk or both still doesn't make it work :/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has been solved [HERE](https://answers.unity.com/questions/185841/rigidbody-objects-not-colliding.html) , in short it is because only convex mesh colliders can collide with each other. (Your right one is convex and the left one is not).

Comment: Hi! I have already tried it but still doesn't push the disks off the conveyor belt